# Call arrow function inside arrow function. React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app with react native and expo. How can I call adjacent function inside arrow function. `funcTwo` does not get called from `funcOne` and no warnings/errors show up.

```
// Call first fucntion inside MainScreen.js
import Fire from '../Fire';
export default class MainScreen extends React.Component {
    makeRemoteRequest = async () => {
        const res = await Fire.shared.funcOne({ title: "test" });
    }
};

// Fire.js
class Fire {
    funcOne = async ({title}) => {
        this.funcTwo(title);
    };

    funcTwo = async (title) => {
        // save to database
        console.log(title);
    };
}
Fire.shared = new Fire();
export default Fire;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `class Fire extends React.Component`

Comment: @IshanJoshi please see update code

Comment: [This seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/d4z2mcbr/1/), though I'm not definitively saying their isn't something wrong with the React portion, as I'm not entirely familiar with it.

Comment: It is working fine. What is the exact issue?

Comment: If you're going to use `await`, you have to declare the async prefix, like `async componentDidMount() {`

Comment: @acdcjunior is there a difference between doing `makeRemoteRequest = async () => {` vs `async makeRemoteRequest() {` I updated the code to show how i'm calling it

Comment: The way you are doing now is the correct one. The other possibility you mentioned in your last comment wouldn't work. Anyway, your code now shouldn't have any problem. Can you post the code that calls `makeRemoteRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `await` within `funcOne` when you call `funcTwo`
you can omit `await` if you are returning the value of `funcTwo` but you aren't

So ..

```
// Call first fucntion inside MainScreen.js
import Fire from '../Fire';
export default class MainScreen extends React.Component {
    makeRemoteRequest = async () => {
        const res = await Fire.shared.funcOne({ title: "test" });
    }
};

// Fire.js
class Fire {
    funcOne = async ({title}) => {
    // Here you should add await
        await this.funcTwo(title);
    // or 
    // return this.funcTwo(title);
    };

    funcTwo = async (title) => {
        // save to database
        console.log(title);
    };
}
Fire.shared = new Fire();
export default Fire;
```